# Class Composition Error?

Tags: objective-c

I wonder if someone can explain where I am going wrong here, I am creating 2 objects (car & engine) where the car object contains a pointer to the engine object. I know I am missing the obvious or just making some silly mistake, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

NB: the code all works, except for the line that is comment ERROR.

```
// INTERFACE ------------------------------------------------------- **
@interface EngineClass : NSObject {
}
@end


@interface CarClass : NSObject {
    EngineClass *engine;
}
- (void)setEngine:(EngineClass *)value;
@end


// IMPLEMENT ------------------------------------------------------- **
@implementation CarClass

- (void)setEngine:(EngineClass *)newEngine {
    if (engine != newEngine) {
        [engine release];
        engine = [newEngine copy];
    }
}
@end

@implementation EngineClass
@end


// MAIN ------------------------------------------------------------ **

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CarClass *newCar_001;
    EngineClass *newEngine_001;

    newCar_001 = [[CarClass alloc] init];
    newEngine_001 = [[EngineClass alloc] init];

    [newCar_001 setEngine: newEngine_001]; // ERROR

    // Clean up
    [newCar_001 release];
    [newEngine_001 release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
// END ------------------------------------------------------------- **
```

The ERROR is ....

run
2009-09-22 13:41:05.483 cocoa_engine_TEST[8606:a0f] 
2009-09-22 13:41:05.485 cocoa_engine_TEST[8606:a0f] 
2009-09-22 13:41:05.485 cocoa_engine_TEST[8606:a0f] -[EngineClass copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10010c8d0
2009-09-22 13:41:05.486 cocoa_engine_TEST[8606:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EngineClass copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10010c8d0'

cheers -gary-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for the copy method:

> This is a convenience method for
>   classes that adopt the NSCopying
>   protocol. An exception is raised if
>   there is no implementation for
>   copyWithZone:.

Have you implemented copyWithZone?

And why copy engine when you could just retain?

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    EngineClass *engineCopy = [[EngineClass allocWithZone: zone] init];
    // copy variables here, deep or shallow
    return engineCopy;
}
```

It returns a retained object, as copy methods should.

Comment: the copy came from running the "Place Accessor Defs On Clipboard" from the xcode menu using "EngineClass *engine;" As for why copy rather than retain, my understanding was that -copy ensures that if someone passes in an instance then you make a copy to work with incase the original changes? probably getting mixed up I guess ...

Comment: If there's a reason to work with a copy rather than the original, then you should use copy. You just need to remember to implement copywithZone in your EngineClass. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi Terry, do you have any idea how an implementation of copywithZone might look in EngineClass. I am only just learning Objective-C (3 weeks in) and it a little beyond where I am at, but I am interested to find out for future reference.

Comment: So where I am going wrong is essentially besause I am copying an instance of a class, rather then in previous examples where I was copying single variables or NSString objects.

Comment: NSString objects -are- an instance of a class. The point is that the NSString class already implements copyWithZone, but your EngineClass class does not.

Comment: Yes, that's where you're going wrong. As andyvn22 points out, an NSString is an instance of a class, but it already implements copyWithZone. Your EngineClass also need to implement it. How to implement it gets discussed in http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmImplementCopy.html .

Comment: Ah I see, now I understand, can anyone expalin to a beginner how I would add that to my class (i.e. what code I would need to add)?

Comment: @fuzzygoat: You create a new object and set its state to match the original's.